# php mysql IN clause not working with CSV variable. only first row is affected

Tags: php, mysql, csv

when i query the database using php my admin the following sql works

```
update invoice
set paid = 1, date_recieved = 0000-00-00, check_number = 00000
where invoice_number IN (110038,110035,110033)
```

i have a text box where a user enters numbers separated by a comma. this is submitted via post to the $invoice variable. 
when i run the following only the first row is affected.
the code commented out is things that i tried but didn't work

```
if(isset($_POST["paymentbtn"])){
    $invoice = $_POST["invoice"];
    //$data = array($invoice);
    //$data = implode(",", $data);
    $date = $_POST["date"];
    $check = $_POST["checknumber"];
    //$invoice = mysql_real_escape_string($invoice);
    $sql = mysql_query("update invoice set paid = 1, date_recieved = '$date',     check_number = '$check'
where invoice_number IN ('$invoice')" )or die (mysql_error());
}
```

im probability missing something simple

p.s. it also works when i just enter one value so its not an invalid date or anything

Comment: Use implode then make a loop.

Comment: Try `foreach($_POST['invoice'] as $val){
    $values[] = $val;
}
$inv = implode(", ", $values);`

then `where invoice_number IN('$inv')")`

Comment: that didn't work. it wont make any changes to the db like that a single number or multiple. does what you are doing with the implode add a ',' between values. if so are you missing the leading ' ?

Comment: the foreach didn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use ' ' for  $invoice because when you use it is like  '1,2,3' where it should either be like '1','2','3' or 1,2,3

I think your query should be as below

"update invoice set paid = 1, date_recieved = '$date', check_number = '$check' where invoice_number IN ($invoice)"